# Truth of $A\subseteq \Omega$ and $P(A)=1$ then $A=\Omega$ and if $P(A)=0$ then $A=\phi$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $\Omega$ be the sample space and $A\subseteq\Omega$ be an event. Given below are two statements:

$(S1)$: If $P(A)=0$, then $A=\phi$

$(S2)$ :If $P(A)=1$, then $A=\Omega$

Then which of the following statements hold :

1. Both $(S1)$ and $(S2)$ are false.
2. Both $(S1)$ and $(S2)$ are true.
3. Only $(S1)$ is true.
4. Only $(S2)$ is true.

Answer given is 1. but I think answer must be 2. or am I missing something. Can there be counterexamples to 2.

Comment: Consider probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)=( [0,1], \mathcal B([0,1]), \lambda)$, where $\mathcal B([0,1])$ is Borel $\sigma-$field and $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$. Then $A = \{0\}$ satisfies $\mathbb P(A) = 0$ but $A \neq \emptyset$. Hence, $A^c = (0,1]$ satisfies $\mathbb P(A^c) = 1$ but $A^c \neq \Omega$.

Comment: You can have a sample space with a nonempty set of probability zero.  It could even happen in a sample space of two elements: one element of probability zero and the other of probability one.

Comment: There are many "formal" counterexamples . For example taking $[0,1]$ with the Lebesgue measure and Borel Sigma algebra , the measure(probability) of rationals is $0$. But intuitively , think of throwing a die infinitely many times.  Then the probability of getting all outcomes to be $6$ is $0$, but does it mean that it cannot happen(i.e. is $(6,6,.....)\notin\Omega)$ ? . No ofcourse not , it can indeed happen.

Comment: @GEdgar Can you give an example

Comment: Example.  $\Omega = \{1,2\}$, $P(\varnothing) = P(\{1\}) = 0$, $P(\{2\})=P(\Omega)=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine the unit interval $[0,1]$ with the usual Lebesgue measure. Taking $A=\{0\}$ (clearly non-empty) shows $P(A)=0$ (singletons have zero Lebesgue measure). Taking $A=[0,1)$ shows $P(A)=1-0=1$ (the length of the interval), but clearly $A\neq [0,1]$. So, S1 and S2 are both false.

If you want a more extreme example, let $C\subset [0,1]$ be the middle-thirds Cantor set. Then, this is an uncountably infinite set with $P(C)=0$, and hence $P([0,1]\setminus C)=1$. So, $C$ shows that $(S1)$ is false, and $[0,1]\setminus C$ shows that $(S2)$ is false.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: consider $\Omega = [0, 1]$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and uniform probability measure (defined via the Lebesgue measure).

Let $A=\{1/2\}$. What is $P(A)$ and $P(\Omega\setminus A)$?